# Winrt & Xaml: Grid with Scrollbar ... tried Stackpanel, Scrollviewer, can't see to get it to work

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I am trying to get a scrollbar on on a grid for WinRT app with Xaml.  Basic page setup has an overal grid for the top and middle sections.  Inside the middle section I put another grid with 2 rows and 2 columns.  Inside row 1 col 1 of that grid, I want to put a Border with another grid inside of data to display and have a scroll bar inside the border area.

I have racked my brains on this for, roughly, 3 days now on and off and searched all over the net

I have roughly tried these two methods, which, I think should work, but don't.  Simplified, but the grids of textboxes has about 30 grids of textboxes to show.

```
<Grid x:Name="PersonViewContent" Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="MainScrollViewer"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ZoomMode="Disabled"
        IsTabStop="False"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Padding="0,0,0,20">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition
                    Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="500"
                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ScrollViewer
                    x:Name="PersonScroller"
                    Margin="0"
                    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                    FontSize="20"
                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="true"
                    IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                    IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
                    IsHoldingEnabled="False"
                    IsRightTapEnabled="False"
                    IsTapEnabled="False">
                    <StackPanel
                        Margin="0"
                        Width="490"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid
                            Height="250"
                            Margin="10,10,10,10"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <Image
                                Source="{Binding Image}"
                                AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ImageSourceSubtitle}"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Stretch="{Binding ImageStretch}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Subtitle}"
                                Margin="0,180,0,0"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock"
                                Margin="5,10,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="Textblock: "
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                MaxHeight="60"
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Margin="152,0,0,0"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The next method I tried simplified things into a more logical grid, but, still can't get it working.  Imagine the `TextBlock`s there for 30 rows.  Here, when run, the `ScrollBar` shows, but doesn't do anything even though the text is clearly off the bottom of the border area and you can't see the bottom of the border area.

This is now sample code directly from my code, from the top of the page to the bottom of the grid in question:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="PersonViewContent" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Width="500" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="270" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <Image Source="text" AutomationProperties.Name="text" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="text"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="text" Margin="0,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="text" Margin="0,215,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,0,18,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" MaxHeight="60" FontSize="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,10,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataHeaderStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="17" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataHeaderStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="21" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="21" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="23" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataHeaderStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="24" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="24" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="25" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="25" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="26" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="26" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="0" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="1" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="28" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ViewPersonTextDataHeaderStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="29" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="text" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" IsTapEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Anyway, spinning my wheels on this... hoping for a suggestion

Edited:
Here's roughly a sketch of the layout I am trying to achieve:

```
|=========================================
|back button and title area              |
|                                        |
| |===============|                      |
| |               | Grid View here for   |
| | Picture area  | other stuff that the |
| |               | User can click on    |
| | Start of text |                      |
| | data of all   |                      |
| | textblocks    |                      |
| | 30+ rows      |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| | textblock     |                      |
| |===============|                      |
|========================================|
```

Comment: any chance you could post/upload a mockup of the UI you want to achieve?  I'm having trouble following the description.

Comment: I agree with Jim on that. I cleaned up your code a bit, but it doesn't make much sense as it stands. One thing worth noting though is that instead of a `ScrollViewer` with tons of `TextBlock`s it is almost always better to use something like a `ListView` which will enable list virtualization, so all these TextBlocks don't need to be loaded at the same time and also to make your code cleaner. Please try to sketch your desired design and add it in the edited question to get more help.

Comment: Having trouble getting a sample put in.  Roughly speaking, I am looking for this.  Imagine a XAML page for a Windows Store App.  The left side contains a Border area taking up 1/3 or so of the screen.  Inside this contains a photo as well as 30+ rows of information.  This area is scrollable inside the border area for the user to scroll up and down to see whatever portion of that area that the wish.  The rest of the screen is a gridview for tiles that the user can click on to perform actions of some sort or another.  let me see if I can get the text based mockup inserted.

Answer (score 0):

From the ASCII image you presented, seems like you can achieve the desired layout using a combination of Grid, StackPanel, and ScrollViewer.

```
<Page
x:Class="App15.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App15"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DarkCyan">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Go Back" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Background="DarkOrange" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <Border Background="Crimson" Height="100">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Put picture here</TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock>tb1</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>tb2</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>tb3</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>tb28</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>tb29</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>tb30</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridView Background="DarkViolet" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <GridViewItem>gvi1</GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>gvi2</GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>gvi3</GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works, but I need the border around the whole Column 1 area and two textblocks per row.  Which is why I made a grid inside the border to layout what I needed in the border area.  Picture colspan 2, all the other information 2 per ro1, 1 per column.  I tried listview, but, two textblocks per listview that have to be laid out in a horizontal stackpanel and then the margins have to be messed around with for each entry.  It seems like there should be a way to do border scrollview stackpanel grid stackpanel/ scrollviewer/ border/ .... I edited my original post to have this code listed... as is

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out it isn't anything I am doing wrong in particular.  it's more the Auto attribute for the rows / columns I was using.  It makes the row go off the screen (not sure why) therefore the scrollbar is relatively pointless.

BAsically, re-did the whole thine to do snap vs not snapped different and have all the alignment taken care of.